# Count the average of number of surveys per year, Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Model, called Survey that has a

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date submittedDate;
```

field, which is a timestamp that shows the time that a row is insterted in this table.
What I want to be able to query and show is this :
The total number of rows for every month, 12 months. 
And then find the average. Which would be :

(countJan+CountFeb+...)/12; ( cycle through countInEveryMonth, and divide by 12 )

How do I query this using Spring Data Jpa ?

Do I write a method like :

```
int countBySubmittedDate(Date submittedDate) ? -
```

but this will count the number of Surveys at a given timestamp?
Thank you.

Comment: you have to create your own custom query instead

Comment: can we see the model/enitity?

Answer (score 0):

Whole year average can be:

```java
public interface SurveyRepository extends CrudRepository<Survey, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(s) FROM Survey s WHERE (date_field BETWEEN :yearStart AND :yearEnd)")
    Long yearAverage(@Param("yearStart") Date yearEnd, @Param("yearEnd") Date yearEnd);
    //you may divide it by 12
}
```

Same can be done for other scenario.